# What is "tag" in the result of "adb shell dumpsys alarm"?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

When I create an alarm, this is the result of "adb shell dumpsys" command to get all the alarms set by my app:

```
RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{e99208d type 0 when 1598369880862 ir.zima.schema}
  operation=PendingIntent{92c0242: PendingIntentRecord{1794253 ir.zima.schema broadcastIntent}}
```

When I use same command to check another app's alarms set, I see it like this:

```
 RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{20eda5f type 0 when 1598297400000 com.mobiliha.badesaba}
  tag=*walarm*:com.mobiliha.badesaba/com.mobiliha.receiver.PrayTimeReciver
  operation=PendingIntent{b561cac: PendingIntentRecord{96ecd75 com.mobiliha.badesaba broadcastIntent}}
```

where is this line coming from? What is it used for?

```
tag=*walarm*:com.mobiliha.badesaba/com.mobiliha.receiver.PrayTimeReciver
```

There is no arguments as tag when creating alarms.

```
 alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

Or when you set alarm like this:

```
public void setExact (int type, 
            long triggerAtMillis, 
            String tag, 
            AlarmManager.OnAlarmListener listener, 
            Handler targetHandler)
```

There is a tag, but there is no PendingIntent anymore.
I am confused aobut the result of "adb shell dumpsys alarm" which has both PendingIntent and tag.

Thanks for any clarification in advance

**Update**
This is how I set an alarm at the moment:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager =( AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context//same activity should be used when canceling the alarm
            , AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.NOTIFY");

   
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1001, 
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    
    Calendar time = getTime(hour, minute);//a method that return a calendar Obj
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){

        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
    }

    else{         alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the tag when use `AlarmManager#set` method:

```
public void set (int type, 
                long triggerAtMillis, 
                String tag, 
                AlarmManager.OnAlarmListener listener, 
                Handler targetHandler)
```

> tag - a string describing the alarm, used for logging and battery-use
> attribution

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#set(int,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.AlarmManager.OnAlarmListener,%20android.os.Handler)

**UPD 0:**

The `tag` is null when you pass `PendingIntent` instance.
In this case, the framework creates the tag itself. To figure out how it's done need to do small research:

1. AlarmManagerService:
   https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/a4ddee215e41ea232340c14ef92d6e9f290e5174/services/core/java/com/android/server/AlarmManagerService.java#L3646
2. PendingIntent:
   https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/a4ddee215e41ea232340c14ef92d6e9f290e5174/core/java/android/app/PendingIntent.java#L1146
3. ActivityManagerService:
   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a1f1a3c573acd91024fda0ceb3b921c73b186963/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#5550

As you can see, the final tag is created from an intent's action or component.

**UPD 1:**

```java
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
long alarmTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 30 * 1000;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
intent.setAction("myAlarmAction");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1001,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManagerCompat.setExact(alarmManager, AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        alarmTime, pendingIntent);
```

Output:

```
RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{69a2b91 type 0 when 1598419056411 PendingIntent{d67ec1b: PendingIntentRecord{3759c1 com.sdex.alarmmanager broadcastIntent}}com.sdex.alarmmanager}
  tag=*walarm*:myAlarmAction
  type=0      wakeup=true expectedWhenElapsed=+3s733ms expectedMaxWhenElapsed=+3s733ms whenElapsed=+3s733ms maxWhenElapsed=+3s733ms when=2020-08-26 08:17:36.411
  window=0 repeatInterval=0 count=0 flags=0x1
  operation=PendingIntent{d67ec1b: PendingIntentRecord{3759c1 com.sdex.alarmmanager broadcastIntent}}
```

Comment: I have seen this one. But this one does not accept a PendingIntent. The adb result that I brought as an example in the question has both tag and PendingIntent. I couldn't find anything about that

Comment: Besides, the one that has a tag that you mentioned, doesn't work when you close the app. But the app shared it's log works perfectly

Comment: Thanks for elaboration. It seems like there is a *walarm* or *alarm* tag based on the alarm type in the link you provided. However when I set the alarm, I don't see that tag. I also have an action set for my intent. But there is still no tags in the adb command result

Comment: Can you come up with a reproducible piece of code that actually creates the tag in the adb command result? I will update my code to show you how I create an alarm already.

Comment: I see the tag in dumpsys output: tag=*walarm*:myAlarmAction

Comment: You mean with the same code I added to my question, you see that tag in adb result?

Comment: It's slightly changed, but yes.

Comment: Strange, Because I don't receive it that way. I posted my adb result in the question. Can you think of any specific reason?